# Marklogic: How to connect to Alteryx

Tags: marklogic

Connecting Alteryx to MarkLogic.

How does one connect Alteryx to MarkLogic?

Does anyone have experience with this?

If you have example setup screen shots, or something similar, it would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the 64 bit odbc driver and then setting it up as a generic odbc connection?

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/odbc-driver

Comment: Hej there! I appreciate the effort, but perhaps this answer would be better off being a comment. To be a full blown answer, I feel it show how to install/use the ODBC driver.

Comment: I did install the Marklogic 64 bit ODBC driver and used it to get data into Power BI.   I have yet to have it set up for a user that has Alteryx installed.